# Check whether the process is being run as a pipe

Tags: python, process, pipe, stdio

I have a small Python utility which should be run only as a pipe. I want it to print out the help message when it runs stand alone. How can a process know whether it is being used as a pipe. Comparing `sys.stdin` and `sys.__stdin__` does not work.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use `isatty`:

```
if sys.stdin.isatty():
```

It will be `True` if standard input is a tty, which roughly means it's being used directly, outside a pipe.

Comment: Also `if sys.stdout.isatty()` for the opposite.

Comment: Just a hint: if you start python in a CI environment ala travis, jenkins or gitlab-ci, it might be that `sys.stdin.isatty()` is always `False`.